# How to solve this compile time error from Eigen?

Tags: matrix, vector, eigen, eigen3

I am using Eigen Library and in my class I am trying to implement a kalman filter so there are a lot of matrix of vector manipulation. However, I get a compile time error , while the object is actually being created and before any mathematical  operations

before any inialization , the program aborts and I get this error

```
eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:285: 
void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::resize(Eigen::Index, Eigen::Index) 
[with Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>; Eigen::Index = long int]: Assertion `(!(RowsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) || (rows==RowsAtCompileTime)) && (!(ColsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) || (cols==ColsAtCompileTime)) && (!(RowsAtCompileTime==Dynamic && MaxRowsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) || (rows<=MaxRowsAtCompileTime)) && (!(ColsAtCompileTime==Dynamic && MaxColsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) || (cols<=MaxColsAtCompileTime)) && rows>=0 && cols>=0 && "Invalid sizes when resizing a matrix or array."' failed.
```

is it a common known error ? or I am trying to debug it for hours now but somehow cluless as i am sure of my matrix dimensions (so far)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are trying to resize a `Matrix4d` to a size other than 4x4. If you don't know the size of your matrix at compile time, use `MatrixXd`. Also, better provide a [mre].

Comment: I already found it ! Thanks for the help !